# Convert delimited string and value into hierarchical JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, tree, hierarchical-data, delimited

I have data in the following format:

```
[['Director', 9010],
['Director - Product Manager', 9894],
['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager', 9080],
['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff', 5090],
['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff 2', 5087],
['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager 2', 9099],...]
```

and want an output that'll look something like this:

```
{
    'title': 'Director',
    'id': 9010,
    'children': [
        {
            'title': 'Product Manager',
            'id': 9894,
            'children': [
                {
                    'title': 'Project Manager',
                    'id': 9080,
                    'children': [
                        ...
                    ]
                },{
                    'title': 'Project Manager 2',
                    'id': 9099,
                    'children': [
                        ...
                    ]
                }],
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I've been toying around with dictionaries, but struggling to match the ids with the titles. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you tried please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An efficient way to do this is to make the outermost layer a list rather than a dict. As we iterate over each title in the string of titles we look for a dict with that title in the current list. If the title doesn't exist in the current list then we need to create a new dict. If it does exist, then we make the children list of that dict the new current list and proceed to look for the next title.

I've also written a recursive `prune` function which removes all empty children lists, once we've finished entering all the data, in case you want to do that.

```
import json

lst = [
    ['Director', 9010],
    ['Director - Product Manager', 9894],
    ['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager', 9080],
    ['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff', 5090],
    ['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff 2', 5087],
    ['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager 2', 9099],
]

# Search for a matching name in the current list.
# If it doesn't exist, create it.
def insert(lst, name, idnum):
    for d in lst:
        if d['title'] == name:
            break
    else:
        d = {'title': name, 'id': idnum, 'children': []}
        lst.append(d)
    return d['children']

# Remove empty child lists
def prune(lst):
    for d in lst:
        if d['children']:
            prune(d['children'])
        else:
            del d['children']

# Insert the data into the master list
master = []
for names, idnum in lst:
    lst = master
    for name in [s.strip() for s in names.split(' - ')]:
        lst = insert(lst, name, idnum)

prune(master)

# Get the top level dict from the master list
data = master[0]
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**output**

```
{
    "title": "Director",
    "id": 9010,
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "Product Manager",
            "id": 9894,
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Project Manager",
                    "id": 9080,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "Staff",
                            "id": 5090
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Staff 2",
                            "id": 5087
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Project Manager 2",
                    "id": 9099
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `d` as your input,  iterate through your input list with.

Since there are two elements in every sublists, hold the position and id in the iteration variable as `p` and `id`

Example, you are processing list `['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff', 5090],`

To get the title of each position, you can split your the position separated by `-` and strip the leading and trailing white spaces. Eg.,

```
>>> d[3][0]
'Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff'
>>> map(str.strip,d[3][0].split('-'))
['Director', 'Product Manager', 'Project Manager', 'Staff']
```

The output dict, along with the immediately previous position of `Staff` is passed to the recursive search method and it fetches the all matches of the finding value, i.e. `Project Manager` and returns a list. Fetch the last match.

```
>>> recursive_search([data,],'Product Manager')[-1]
{'children': [{'children': [{'id': 5090, 'title': 'Staff'}, {'id': 5087, 'title': 'Staff 2'}], 'id': 9080, 'title': 'Project Manager'}, {'id': 9099, 'title': 'Project Manager 2'}], 'id': 9894, 'title': 'Product Manager'}
```

You need to append the new id to the `children` key of the above result!

Combining all the above,

```
d=[['Director', 9010],['Director - Product Manager', 9894],['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager', 9080],['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff', 5090],['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager - Staff 2', 5087],['Director - Product Manager - Project Manager 2', 9099],]

from pprint import pprint    
def recursive_search(items, key):
        found = []
        for item in items:
                if isinstance(item, list):
                        found += recursive_search(item, key)
                elif isinstance(item, dict):
                        if key in item.values():
                                found.append(item)
                        found += recursive_search(item.values(), key)
        return found
data={}
for p,id in d:
        desig = map(str.strip,p.split('-'))
        if len(desig)>1:
                res = recursive_search([data,],desig[-2])[-1]
                if res:
                        res['children']=res.get('children',[])
                        res['children'].append({'id':id,'title':desig[-1]})
        else:
                data = {'id':id,'title':p}

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'children': [{'children': [{'children': [{'id': 5090, 'title': 'Staff'},
                                          {'id': 5087,
                                           'title': 'Staff 2'}],
                             'id': 9080,
                             'title': 'Project Manager'},
                            {'id': 9099, 'title': 'Project Manager 2'}],
               'id': 9894,
               'title': 'Product Manager'}],
 'id': 9010,
 'title': 'Director'}
```

Ref: The recursive_search function used here is the slightly modified version of searching through a dict mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968867/check-a-key-exist-in-entire-list-or-dict-in-python)